# Why doesn't this work for me? [element] [class] {style}

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a normal class for tables, e.g.

`table {style here}`

But for some tables I'd like to have a different style

I could just give the table a class and then use that class alone, e.g.

`.specialTable {special style}`

But I'd like to try specifying that this is just applicable to tables, e.g.

`.specialTable table {special style}`

However this isn't working, what's wrong?

Comment: You would use `table.specialTable`.

Comment: `.specialTable table` means `<table>`s that are *children* of `.specialTable` elements.  Did you mean to use `table.specialTable{}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.specialTable table {special style}
```

The above code will affect *any* table which has an ancestor (a previous element) with the class `specialTable`. That will for instance match the table in

```
<body class="specialTable">
  ...
  <table>
  ...
```

What you want is a table with the class `specialTable` in which case the syntax is

```
table.specialTable {special style}
```

Answer (score 3):

`.specialTable table` specifies a `table` element within an element with the class `specialTable`.

You want `table.specialTable`, which means any `table` *with* the class `specialTable`.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you showed your HTML but I think I see what you're getting at.

`<table class="specialTable">` is not what your CSS specifies. Instead it specifies something like

```
<div class="specialTable"><table>...</table></div>
```

Instead in your CSS you can do

```
table.specialTable { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.specialTable table` Is selecting tables that are descendants of elements with the `.specialTable` class.

You want `table.specialTable`, which selects tables with the class specialTable.